# when should i use more than one controller in my app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

So recently I started to learn angularJS and I'm working on a SPA project.
it is a game with several steps (the purpose of the game isn't important for the matter of the question)

At the moment i have a controller for each one of the steps, all of them are childs of a mainControlelr so in my html it looks something like:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<!--main container-->
<div class="row">
    <!--center pane-->
    <div id="centerPane" class="col-lg-8 center-block">
        .
        .   some code...
        .
        <!--steps--> 
        <div ng-view id="form-views"></div>

        .
        .   some code...
        .

    </div>
        .
        .   some code...
        .
</div>
```

after speaking with some of my friends, all of them told me that this isn't a good way to do it and i should do one of the following instead:

1. work with only one controller (for this exmaple, 'mainCtrl')
2. keep the code like this, but inject a specific service, to all of my controllers,  which will hold all of my global vars and make sure the controllers are updating the service vars.

so basically my question is when, as a rule of thumb, one should consider using more than one controller in a SPA?

Thanks,

Comment: almost always u can use as many controllers as possible, If you use only one controller your code will get monolithic and hard to  maintain

Comment: create custom directives so that your application is broken down into smaller fragments, that way it will be easier to maintain and unit test. Each of those custom directives can have their own controller and can have isolated scopes if you want. Understanding directive have a learning curve but once you get hold of the knowledge its a cake walk.

Comment: @dishwasherWithProgrammingSkill
yes i made directives,
i asked "when, as a rule of thumb, one should consider using more than one controller in a SPA?"
i want to know what is the best thing to do when building a SPA

Comment: @asafel the point with directives is that by creating directives you also create separate controllers instead of one big one

Comment: @squillman
I must say, what you have just said sounds really weird... directives are a way to organize your html code (by creating your own tags) and handle with repeated code throughout your app, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @asafel There is no rule of thumb in when and where one should create multiple controller. But generally speaking, if you already have broken you codes into directives, it is better to move the logic related to those directives from the parent controller to the controllers in their respective directives. That way you prevent a monolithic controller and will be easy to maintain as each piece of logic resides with their respective directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I would advise **against** putting all your code in one controller. This makes it very hard to understand, as a lot of business logic will be in one file, and it will be hard to unit-test.

First of all, business logic should be put in a service. Keep as much business logic out of the controller and put it in a service or factory.

Assuming you're using ngRoute (I see `ng-view` in your code) and the steps are one after the other, I would suggest to make full use of the ngRoute component. What this means is that every step in your application should have it's own route and companying controller. As previously stated, business logic that applies to multiple routes should be abstracted to a service or factory.

To make it more clear, the below code could be the configuration of the routes for every step.

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/step-1', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/step1.html',
       controller: 'StepOneCtrl'
      }).
     when('/step-2', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/step2.html',
      controller: 'StepTwoCtrl'
     }).
     otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/step-1'
     });
  }]);
```

Comment: great, thanks
exactly as i thought. just wanted to make sure im doing things the right way